# Fetching data back from datastore in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

**My Index.yaml file **

```
`
indexes:
- kind: company
properties:
- name: company_email
direction: asc # or DESC based on your query requirements
- name: company_name
direction: asc # or DESC based on your query requirements

`
```

**My Function: **

```
def get_company_name_by_email(company_email):
  client = datastore.Client()

  query = client.query(kind='company')
  query.projection = ['company_name']
  query.add_filter('company_email', '=', company_email)
  query.keys_only()
  query.limit = 1

  results = list(query.fetch())

  if results:
    company_name = results[0]['company_name']
    return company_name
  else:
    return None
```

**
My Usage of this function in views.py **

**
class UserLoginView(APIView):

```
def post(self, request):
    serializer = UserLoginSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        # Update to match the serializer field names: company_email
        email = serializer.validated_data.get('company_email')
        
        # Debugging: Print the email obtained from the serializer
        print("Email received:", email)

        if email:
            # Fetch company name associated with the email from the datastore
            company_name = get_company_name_by_email(email)

            if company_name:
                # Authentication successful, return the company name along with the response
                return Response({'message': 'Login successful', 'company_name': company_name}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            else:
                # Handle scenario where company name is not found
                return Response({'message': 'Company name not found for the given email'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        else:
            # Handle scenario where email is not found in the request data
            return Response({'message': 'Email not provided or invalid'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    else:
        # Handle serializer validation errors
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**

**Error: **

Email received:
/Users/emblemdevice/Desktop/final/Djangobackend/loginapp/datastore_ops.py:9: UserWarning: Detected filter using positional arguments. Prefer using the 'filter' keyword argument instead.
query.add_filter('company_email', '=', company_email)
Internal Server Error: /api/login/
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 75, in error_remapped_callable
return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 1161, in **call**
return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 1004, in _end_unary_response_blocking
raise _InactiveRpcError(state)  # pytype: disable=not-instantiable
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
status = StatusCode.FAILED_PRECONDITION
details = "The query requires an ASC or DESC index for kind company and property company_email. Please use the gcloud CLI to remove the single-property index exemption for this property."
debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer ipv4:172.217.17.42:443 {grpc_message:"The query requires an ASC or DESC index for kind company and property company_email. Please use the gcloud CLI to remove the single-property index exemption for this property.", grpc_status:9, created_time:"2023-12-20T13:40:36.704933+00:00"}"

> 

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
response = get_response(request)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 65, in _view_wrapper
return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 104, in view
return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
response = self.handle_exception(exc)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
raise exc
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Users/emblemdevice/Desktop/final/Djangobackend/loginapp/views.py", line 18, in post
company_name = get_company_name_by_email(email)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Users/emblemdevice/Desktop/final/Djangobackend/loginapp/datastore_ops.py", line 13, in get_company_name_by_email
results = list(query.fetch())
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/api_core/page_iterator.py", line 208, in _items_iter
for page in self._page_iter(increment=False):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/api_core/page_iterator.py", line 244, in _page_iter
page = self._next_page()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore/query.py", line 814, in _next_page
response_pb = self.client._datastore_api.run_query(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore_v1/services/datastore/client.py", line 637, in run_query
response = rpc(
^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 131, in **call**
return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 366, in retry_wrapped_func
return retry_target(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 204, in retry_target
return target()
^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/api_core/timeout.py", line 120, in func_with_timeout
return func(*args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 77, in error_remapped_callable
raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc
google.api_core.exceptions.FailedPrecondition: 400 The query requires an ASC or DESC index for kind company and property company_email. Please use the gcloud CLI to remove the single-property index exemption for this property.
[20/Dec/2023 13:40:36] "POST /api/login/? HTTP/1.1" 500 155546

Comment: What do you get from `gcloud datastore indexes list` (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/datastore/indexes/list)?

Did you run `gcloud datastore indexes create`?  Has the composite index finished building?